# Can someone check my proof? (connectedness of real projective hyperquadrics)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Theorem: Let $Q_{\mathbb{R}} \subset \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ the set of real points of a projective hyperquadric. Prove that $Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ is connected with the topology induced by $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Show with a counterexample that the theorem is not true in general for hypersurfaces of degree $>2$.

My proof:
I prove it by induction on $n$.

Base case $n=2$:

I have to show that the conic sections of  $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ are connected.  The degenerate case is trivial because they are union of two connected space (two lines) with nonempty intersection.
The nondegenerate conic sections are all homeomorphic (by the stereographic projection) to $ \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ and, therefore, they are connected spaces.

Inductive step: I suppose that the theorem is true for $n-1$ and I prove the case $n$.

Let  $Q_{\mathbb{R}} \subset \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ the set of real points of a projective hyperquadric and suppose by contradiction that $Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ is not connected.

So there exists two disjoint nonempty open set $U$ and $V$ of $Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that 
$$ Q_{\mathbb{R}}=U  \cup V. $$
Because $Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ has the topology induced by $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ we have 
$$ U=U_1 \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}} \textrm{   and   } V=V_1 \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}},$$
where $U_1$ and $V_1$ are open set of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$.
Now choose two points in $U$ and $V$ and an hyperplane $\pi$ of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ which contains these two points. 
We have:
$$ \pi \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}}=((\pi \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}}) \cap (\pi \cap U_1)) \cup ((\pi \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}}) \cap (\pi \cap V_1)),$$
where $ \pi \cap U_1$ and $ \pi \cap V_1$ are disjoint nonempty open set of $\pi$ with the topology induced on it by $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$.
So we proved that the subspace $ \pi \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ of $\pi$ is not connected. But $\pi $ with the topology induced by $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $ \pi \cap Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the set of real points of an hyperquadric of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{R}}$ which, for the inductive step, has to be connected.
So we have the contradiction and, therefore, $Q_{\mathbb{R}}$ has to be a connected space.

A counterexample:
Consider the homogeneous polynomial $ f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2) $.
The set  $C$ of real points of the hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ defined by it, consists of only two points ( $[0,0,1]$ and $[1,0,0]$). So, because $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ is an Hausdorff space, $C$ is not connected.

Comment: It's ok.
But I would just pick two general points, a general hyperplane that contains both  and use the induction. (Note that you've proved that it is path-connected for $n=2$.)

Comment: There are simpler counterexamples. For example, the projectivization of the affine curve $y^2 = x^3 - x$ has two connected components.

Comment: Thank you. I choose two points in $U$ and $V$ to ensure that $\pi \cap U_1$ and $\pi \cap V_1$ are nonempty open set of $\pi$.

Comment: Of course! But, since every hyperquadric of lower dimension is path-connected, you don't need this argument. Just take any two distinct points. a general hyperplane will cut in a hyperquadric of lower dimension and you get the path.

Comment: Now i understand, thank you again!